# Cart - only one item at a time

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2

In my cart on Commerce, I only get to have one item at a time. If I try to add another item, it replaces the item that was already in the cart.

I have used `{% set cart = craft.commerce.getCart() %}` and the for item in `cart.lineItem` to loop through the items, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

That would happen if you are using Commerce Lite. You will need Commerce Pro if you want the 'full' cart functionality.